# Multi domains rewrite with one laravel application

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one laravel application that coordinate multiple domains.

```
public function showWelcome()
{
    switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
    {
        case 'site1':
            return View::make('site1.public.index');
            break;

        case 'site2':
            return View::make('site2.public.index');
            break;

        case 'site3':
            return View::make('site3.public.index');
            break;
    }
}
```

When i type site1.com - everything is working, but when i type www.site1.com - just white screen.
The others domains have the same problems.

I tried to fix it with .htaccess and if i type the first domain (with or without www) - just working. If i type other domain site2.com or www.site2.com for example - redirect to site1.com

Also i tried this:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, 4) == 'www.') {
$domain = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 4);
} else {
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}
```

But not working.
All domains goes to showWelcome() method.

The result has to be:

site1.com or www.site1.com --> case 'site1'
site2.com or www.site2.com --> case 'site2'
site3.com or www.site3.com --> case 'site3'

At the moment only working:

site1.com --> case 'site1'
site2.com --> case 'site2'
site3.com --> case 'site3'

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should consider using the "domain" route groups in your routing file in laravel, which has great support for domains.
Example of routes.php file:

```
$site1Routes = function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {  return View::make('site1.public.index'); });
}

$site2Routes = function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {  return View::make('site2.public.index'); });
}

$site3Routes = function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {  return View::make('site3.public.index'); });
}

Route::group(array('domain' => 'site1.com'), $site1Routes);
Route::group(array('domain' => 'www.site1.com'), $site1Routes);

Route::group(array('domain' => 'site2.com'), $site2Routes);
Route::group(array('domain' => 'www.site2.com'), $site2Routes);

Route::group(array('domain' => 'site3.com'), $site3Routes);
Route::group(array('domain' => 'www.site3.com'), $site3Routes);
```

A quick fix for your current script, could be to simple replace `www.` with `EMPTY`, and that way exclude it from the servername string.

```
public function showWelcome()
{

    $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $domain = str_replace('www.','', $domain);

    switch ($domain)
    {
        case 'site1':
            return View::make('site1.public.index');
            break;

        case 'site2':
            return View::make('site2.public.index');
            break;

        case 'site3':
            return View::make('site3.public.index');
            break;
    }
}
```